# EOS Utility doesn't show exposure meter in manual mode

Tags: canon, eos-utility

EOS Utility doesn't show exposure meter in manual model. In manual i usually adjust the exposure by stopping up and down. You cant adjust this on manual. It lets you adjust in AV and TV but not manual. How is this adjusted in the Utility? There has to be a way.

Comment: At a guess. When you use AV/TV mode the cam is adjusting the Shutter or Aperture to step the exposure up or down. In full manual the user would not want to do this because its full manual. However im not sure why its not giving you an exposure reading...

Comment: Not having used the utility in question... is this computer-based tethering software?

Answer (score 1):

I just did a bit of Googleing and found this [thread](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1075656)

Lifted from the thread:

> Actually you aren't seeing the exposure meter in Av, Tv and P modes...
>   You are seeing the Exposure Compensation display.
>
> There's no use of Exposure Compensation in M mode, so it's blanked out
>   in EOS Utility.
>
> So in other words you really don't see the exposure meter remotely in
>   any mode. You only see Exposure Compensation in modes that can use it.

These is no real use for the exposure compensation display in manual mode via the EOS utility. The cam decides the relevant aspect(aperture / shutter speed) to change in TV and AV modes - where as in full manual mode the utility is probably expecting you to alter this based on say a light reading / or other method to decide exposure.

If you were to use this exposure compensation display in full manual mode you would have to interpret how to adjust the shutter or aperture yourself according to the bar - not as accurate as other means. It would be far easier to take a shot with AV / TV mode, note the settings and move to manual mode or as suggested in the thread you could use live view / histogram to check for correct exposure.

Another suggestion would be to use a light meter to get the correct exposure for your shot.

Comment: Funny... the guy who asked the same question on that thread is also called Jack. maybe its a name thing...